# Adding a id IN (1, 2, ...) to a elastic search query and aggregate counts per id

Tags: php, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have an ES query:

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "content",
            "query" : "this AND that OR thus"
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to

1. Limit the results to specific user_ids (Filter?)
2. Aggregate the counts per user_id

So a similar MySQL query would be `SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) WHERE user_id IN (1, 2, ...) AND (content LIKE '%this%' ...) GROUP BY user_id`

- _id is not the user_id on which I'd like to group by and aggregate count, it's an internal field.

How do I do that in ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `terms` query and another `terms` aggregation on the `user_id` field, like this:

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": {
            "query_string": {
               "default_field": "content",
               "query": "this AND that OR thus"
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "terms": {
               "user_id": [
                  1,
                  2,
                  3
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "by_user": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "user_id"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Too much luck, worked the first time. I'm now trying to only bring back the aggregation part. Direction? btw other than the official ES docs, any recommended cheat-sheet examples?

Comment: Add `"size": 0` above `"query"`. The official doc is pretty comprehensive and can get you going.